# Why can't I get datepicker to work with this TypeError: o is undefined error?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have the following code at the bottom of my page (right before I close the body tag)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

I double-checked through my "view source" to make sure the links aren't broken and everything is there as it should be.

In my `main.js` file I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    imp_init_fields();
});

function imp_init_fields() {
    if( $('.datepicker')[0] ) {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    }
}
```

As you can see, nothing particularly crazy, just setting up a datepicker as I have done it a million times.

Now, when I go on the page in question and I click on my text input the calendar popup appears. However, as soon as I try to interact with the calendar (change month, pick a date, or anything) nothing happens and I get the following error:

Firefox:

> Timestamp: 11/12/2013 2:15:31 PM Error: TypeError: o is undefined
>   Source File:
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js
>   Line: 9

Chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined

Now I've done this a million times and so I figure it's something really simple. I thought maybe I had conflicting versions of jquery and jquery-ui but I went and downloaded the legacy code and I got the same error.

What I don't understand is the datepicker gets initialized and I can make it appear when clicking on the input field but it breaks as soon as I try to interact with it... Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit: I ran it with unminified code.

Firefox:

> Timestamp: 11/12/2013 2:34:45 PM Error: TypeError: inst is undefined
>   Source File: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js Line: 8574

Line 8574:

```
inst.selectedDay = inst.currentDay = $("a", td).html();
```

Unfortunately that doesn't tell me much. I'm not doing anything particularly fancy. I have no other javascript included, this is a very barebone page.

Comment: just to make sure, look at this in your first paste: <script src="http://

Comment: If you used an unminified version of jQuery and jQuery UI, you would actually be able to debug and see what line the error was really on.

Comment: @Gotschi that doesn't break the link, it just makes it so it loads the script through HTTP or HTTPS depending on what I'm using.

Comment: @adeneo I included the errors with the line of code of the file. It doesn't mean much to me. I've done this a bajillion times so I don't understand why it's suddenly broken -- I think I might be overlooking something but I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: Found the same error here with a solution.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375280/jquery-datepicker-returns-inst-is-null-error-when-loaded-via-ajax

Answer (score 4):

After @Melonheadjr44 posted the link to [jQuery datepicker returns "inst is null" error when loaded via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375280/jquery-datepicker-returns-inst-is-null-error-when-loaded-via-ajax) it made me look if I could have two IDs that are conflicting on my page.

Turns out I had done the following:

```
<label id="client_since">Client since:</label>
<input type="text" id="client_since" name="client_since" class="datepicker" value="" />
```

It might not be super clear but I had accidentally swapped the "for" attribute on my label with "id". Since jquery was using the ID to fetch my input box it was actually pulling the label and not finding attributes/options it was expecting to find.